# could not convert string in a flot. random forest classifier fitting

Tags: python, arrays, string, classification, random-forest

1. 

this is my dataframe, with number and columns and time index.
I have also dropped all the not present data...when i try to fit my random forest i have thes error: could not convert string to float.
Can someone help me?
thank you soo much for the help.

```
    high    low     open    volumefrom  volumeto    close   conversionType  conversionSymbol
```

time
2022-07-12 12:40:00     19888.51    19863.07    19886.30    15.12   300423.13   19868.86    direct
2022-07-12 12:41:00     19885.26    19868.86    19868.86    36.72   729798.45   19882.74    direct
2022-07-12 12:42:00     19883.13    19867.63    19882.74    14.50   288215.28   19871.42    direct
2022-07-12 12:43:00     19881.84    19869.38    19871.42    26.22   521042.90   19872.67    direct
2022-07-12 12:44:00     19898.27    19870.60    19872.67    23.07   458804.48   19897.77

2.this i my x columns use for random forest

```
in: `print(X.columns)`

out: Index(['volumefrom', 'conversionSymbol', 'future', 'signal', 'pct_change',
       'pct_change2', 'ATR'],
      dtype='object')
```

3.this is the creation of my random forest classifier

```
rf_model=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=3, max_features=3, max_depth=2, random_state=4)
```

4.this could be the fit

```
rf_model.fit(X_train,y_train['signal'])
```

5.the error is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2022-07-12 13:05:00'
```

6. i have also try to remove the string, but i have the same error with other dates, and others dates.

Comment: Did you encode your categorical (string) features?  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: i have use the one hot encode...but i receive the error...